# Java LocalDateTime parsing

Tags: java, validation, java-time, datetime-parsing

Why can I parse a date time string in java with an invalid hour? What have I missed or need to do to ensure that it throws an error appropriately.

The following code does not throw an error, where it should?

```
DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
LocalDateTime aFormattedDate = LocalDateTime.parse("2019-01-01T24:00:00", dateTimeFormatter); // returns  2019-01-02T00:00:00, should throw an error
```

Specifying the hour as 25, or including any millisecond or other time component does cause `parse` to throw an error.

Where as

```
LocalDateTime aDate = LocalDateTime.parse("2019-01-01T24:00:00"); //throws an error
```

Does throw an error - about HourOfDay needs to be between 0 and 23 - as expected

Comment: This behaviour is emitted with jdk 1.8

Comment: Additionally dates aren't parsed correctly when non-existing leap year dates are parsed, e.g. 2019-02-29T00:00:00

Comment: How is refusing to parse a non-existent date “incorrect”?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## `ResolverStyle`

- [`ResolverStyle.LENIENT`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/ResolverStyle.html#LENIENT)
- [`ResolverStyle.SMART`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/ResolverStyle.html#SMART)
- [`ResolverStyle.STRICT`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/ResolverStyle.html#STRICT)

Because `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern()` defaults to [`ResolverStyle.SMART`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/ResolverStyle.html#SMART) if the resolver style is not specified. `SMART` allows for some conversionse.g. `24:00:00` will be converted to the next day but `24:00:01` will throw an exception. As per the enum javadoc:

> Style to resolve dates and times in a smart, or intelligent, manner.
>
> Using smart resolution will perform the sensible default for each field, which may be the same as strict, the same as lenient, or a third behavior. Individual fields will interpret this differently.
>
> For example, resolving year-month and day-of-month in the ISO calendar system using smart mode will ensure that the day-of-month is from 1 to 31, converting any value beyond the last valid day-of-month to be the last valid day-of-month.

`LocalDateTime.parse()` uses `ResolveStyle.STRICT` under the hood which makes it equivalent to:

```
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")
                                         .withResolverStyle(ResolverStyle.STRICT);
LocalDateTime.parse("2019-01-01T24:00:00", fmt); // DateTimeParseException
```